# ¿se puede obtener elementos bgcolor y cambiar a otra tabla?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Quiero obtener elementos de una tabla por medio del atributo bgcolor="#FFFF75", tengo un ejemplo pero no se como buscar un elemento y pasarlo a otra tabla.

¿alguien a realizado algo parecido en el que pueda seleccionar las filas por bgcolor o algun otro atributo?
Tabla original:

```
<h2>Tabla de información</h2>

<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr bordercolor="#E1E1E1" bgcolor="#FFFF75">
    <td  >Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bordercolor="#E1E1E1" bgcolor="#FFFF75">
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bordercolor="#E1E1E1" bgcolor="#FFFF75">
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
 <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Obtener Elementos</button>
```

Y de hay pasarlo a otra tabla ordenada

```
<table id="tablaresultado">
<tr bordercolor="#E1E1E1" bgcolor="#FFFF75">
    <td  >Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bordercolor="#E1E1E1" bgcolor="#FFFF75">
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bordercolor="#E1E1E1" bgcolor="#FFFF75">
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Realize un ejemplo de mi codigo js pero no tengo experiencia obteniendo elementos de esta manera

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
let obtener_elementos_marcados_buscando_por_el_valor_de_bgcolor="?";
  let elementos_marcados = '<tr bordercolor="#E1E1E1" bgcolor="#FFFF75"> <td>Ernst Handel</td>    <td>Roland Mendel</td>    <td>Austria</td>  </tr>';
  
document.getElementById("tablaresultado").innerHTML  = elementos_marcados;
}

</script>
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con *.... cambiar a otra tabla*?

Comment: hacer una tabla nueva con elementos con la etiqueta   <tr> que tenga un bgcolor="#FFFF75"